# HAML indentation problem IF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, haml

This is my code:

```
-@activities.each do |a|
  -if @i%3 == 0
    %ul
  %li=link_to a.name, a
  -@i += 1
```

I need the li to be inside the ul which is inside the if-statement.
I can't do it because of the indentation. Can't I just tell the li to indent automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you would like to output a new %ul each time when `@i%3 == 0` and then put the `%li` tags there. You can do like the following:

```
-@activities.in_groups_of(3, false) do |activity_group|
  %ul
    -activity_group.each do |activity|
     %li=link_to activity.name, activity
```

To see more information about the topic please visit: http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of